# $\mathbb{Q}$-representation and Galois theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory, galois-theory, noncommutative-algebra

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, we know that all irreducible $\mathbb{Q}$-representation of $G$ is all the subfields of the cyclotomic extension $\mathbb{Q} [\zeta_n]/\mathbb{Q}$, but we know that $\mathrm{Gal} (\mathbb{Q} [\zeta_n ]/\mathbb{Q})\cong (\mathbb{Z} /n\mathbb{Z} )^{\times}$, so I wonder are there a general correspondence between Galois subfields of Galois extensions and representations of some finite groups such that all the irreducible representations of the finite group are exactly all normal subfields of the Galois extension?

Comment: I think that might be very hard as it seems to be related to the inverse Galois problem

Comment: @MaximeRamzi What about a partial answer? i.e. for a given Galois extension, can we find such an abelian group such that its irreducible representations are all normal subfields of this Galois extension?